# SonarQube MSBuild integration failed with Jenkins, works fine on command line

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I am analyzing my .NET project with sonarqube and I want to automate it with my jenkins build server.

I use MSBuild 14.0.23107.0, sonarqube 6.7.1.35068, sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.0.2.892, sonar-csharp-plugin-6.7.1.4347, Jenkins 2.89.3

I tried the jenkins "SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - Begin Analysis" and "SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - End Analysis" build steps but they failed with the following error message:

> The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to
> collect the required information about your projects. Possible causes:
>
> 1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
> 2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 14.0 upwards are supported
> 3. The begin, build or end steps have not all been launched from the same folder

I tried a couple of things and then switched to a windows batch file build step with the following content:

```
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"eGate" /v:"%SVN_REVISION%" /d:sonar.login="%SONAR_AUTH_TOKEN%"
MSBuild.exe /property:Configuration=AutoBuild /t:Rebuild
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end /d:sonar.login="%SONAR_AUTH_TOKEN%"
```

Because this is the most minimal example I could think of. It still fails:

```
12:41:39 C:\Jenkins\workspace\eGate>SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"eGate" /v:"8503" /d:sonar.login="******" 
12:41:39 SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 4.0.2
12:41:39 Default properties file was found at C:\sonarqube\bin\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
12:41:39 Loading analysis properties from C:\sonarqube\bin\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
12:41:39 Pre-processing started.
12:41:39 Preparing working directories...
12:41:39 12:41:39.232  Updating build integration targets...
12:41:39 12:41:39.243  Fetching analysis configuration settings...
12:41:39 12:41:39.403  Provisioning analyzer assemblies for cs...
12:41:39 12:41:39.404  Installing required Roslyn analyzers...
12:41:39 12:41:39.44  Pre-processing succeeded.
12:41:39 
12:41:39 C:\Jenkins\workspace\eGate>MSBuild.exe /property:Configuration=AutoBuild /t:Rebuild 
12:41:39 Microsoft (R)-Buildmodul, Version 14.0.23107.0
```

SNIP

```
12:42:28 
12:42:28     4 Warnung(en)
12:42:28     0 Fehler
12:42:28 
12:42:28 Verstrichene Zeit 00:00:48.97
12:42:28 
12:42:28 C:\Jenkins\workspace\eGate>SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end /d:sonar.login="******" 
12:42:28 SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 4.0.2
12:42:28 Default properties file was found at C:\sonarqube\bin\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
12:42:28 Loading analysis properties from C:\sonarqube\bin\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
12:42:28 Post-processing started.
12:42:28 The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.
12:42:28 Possible causes:
12:42:28   1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
12:42:28   2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 14.0 upwards are supported
12:42:28   3. The begin, build or end steps have not all been launched from the same folder
12:42:28 Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.
12:42:28 12:42:28.73  Creating a summary markdown file...
12:42:28 12:42:28.732  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
12:42:28 
12:42:28 C:\Jenkins\workspace\eGate>exit 1 
12:42:28 Build step 'Windows Batch-Datei ausführen' marked build as failure
12:42:29 Finished: FAILURE
```

The interesting part is, when I open a command line, switch to the jenkins workspace and then execute the commands manually everything works as expected:

```
The SonarQube Scanner has finished
12:28:23.407  Creating a summary markdown file...
12:28:23.411  Analysis results: http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/eGate
12:28:23.411  Post-processing succeeded.
```

Any hints how to debug this? I can provide additional logs and information if you need them.

Comment: I got the same issue. Did you solve it ?

Comment: I added my solution as answer, although I am not 100% happy with it because I still don't know why my relative paths are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could kind of resolve this issue. I am not 100% happy but I can make this work by calling SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe and MSBuild.exe with the full absolute path:

```
"C:\sonarqube\bin\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe" begin /k:"eGate" /v:"%SVN_REVISION /d:sonar.login="%SONAR_AUTH_TOKEN%"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /property:Configuration=AutoBuild /t:Rebuild
"C:\sonarqube\bin\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe" end /d:sonar.login="%SONAR_AUTH_TOKEN%"
```

But I can't figure out why this works but calling them from the %PATH% env doesn't. It is really weird...